# Tab Button Functionality

Tags: javascript, extjs

Is there a way to specifiy what happens when you press the TAB button on your keyboard in EXTJS? From a certain textfield, I want it to TAB right to the submit button after I enter the information in the textfield and press TAB.

Is that possible in EXTJS?

Comment: Can I use something like a keydown or keypress listener?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you already suggested, you can use a listener for the [specialkey](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.1/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Text-event-specialkey) event on your textfield(s):

```
{
    xtype: 'textfield',
    name: 'myfield',
    listeners: {
        specialkey: function(field, e) {
            if (e.getKey() == e.TAB) {
                e.preventDefault();
                Ext.getCmp('mybutton').focus();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** You can also achieve this with negative [tabIndexes](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.1/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Base-cfg-tabIndex), but that will only work correctly if there are no other fields (or other items which may receive focus) between your text fields and the submit button:

```
{
    xtype: 'textfield',
    name: 'myfield1',
    tabIndex: -1
},{
    xtype: 'textfield',
    name: 'myfield2',
    tabIndex: -1
},{
    xtype: 'button',
    name: 'mybutton'
}
```